# How to make URL display as link with https along with current code for http in php?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, preg-replace, nl2br

Thank you for your help.

I currently am using the following code to return URLs as live links on My site:

---

```
//$bodymessage=preg_replace('`((?!##RAQ.*?##)(?<!@)\s[A-Z0-9._-]*\.[A-Z]{2,3}[^ ]*?(?!<[^ \.]))([ \r\n\.])`sim', '##RAQ_URL1##\1..\2##RAQ_URL1##', $bodymessage);

$a_search = array
 (
 '`((?!##RAQ.*?##)[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9._%-]+\.[A-Z0-9._%-]{2,4})\b`sim',
 '`((?!##RAQ.*?##)(?<!@)http://[A-Z0-9._-]*\.[A-Z]{2,3}[^ ]*?(?!<[^ ]))([ \r\n])`sim',
 '`##RAQ_URL1##(.*?)\.\.(.*?)##RAQ_URL1##`sim',
 '`##RAQ_EMAIL##(.*?)##RAQ_EMAIL##`sim',
 );


$a_replace = array
 (
 '##RAQ_EMAIL##\1##RAQ_EMAIL##',
 '##RAQ_URL1##\1..\2##RAQ_URL1##',
 '<a href="\1">\1</a>\2',
 '<a href="mailto:\1">\1</a>',
 );

$message = nl2br(preg_replace($a_search, $a_replace, $bodymessage));
```

---

The script currently displays any 'http' detected into an URL... 
What I'm looking to do is make BOTH 'https' AND 'http' display as an URL...

Thank you very much for your help!

:D

Comment: You should be able to just change `http:` in your pattern to `https?:`

Comment: Thanks Nick.  I want BOTH, Not just https:// or just http:// .  I know I could have just added the 's' in the code for https:// but I need BOTH to work.  Thanks. :)

Comment: Hi Christopher, that's what the `?` in the regexp is for. It means the `s` is optional, so it will match either `http:` or `https:`

Comment: `https?://` does both `s?` means `s` zero or one times.

Comment: Thanks Nick.  I think I read your response as a Q as opposed to an Answer.  I apologize for the misunderstanding. Going to go test this Out.  Thanks!

Comment: Easy enough done - it does look a bit like `https:`?!

Comment: Thanks Scuzzy for your input as well!   How do I award this to Nick? Thanks!

Comment: Hi Christopher, nothing to award as no-one "answered" the question. Just happy to have helped solve the problem.